# Normalize linked ids

Tags: normalizr

I have a weird set of data here.

```
const data = {
    profiles: [
        { name: 'Joe', photos: [1, 2, 3] },
        { name: 'Ryan', photos: [2] },
        { name: 'Bob', photos: null }
    ],
    linked: {
        photos: [
            { id: 1, url: 'http://blah' },
            { id: 2, url: 'blah' },
            { id: 3, url: 'asdf' }
        ]
    }
}
```

I get all the profiles like this:

```
const { entities } = normalize(data, {
    profiles: [ Profile ]
});
```

But I want to replace the `photos` id array with the entries from `linked.photos`, is this possible? Or does it require post processing? I am currently doing custom post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that normalizr is the best aproach for your task, but something like this will work

```js
const photoSchema = new schema.Entity('photos', {});
const normalized = normalize(data.linked.photos, [photoSchema]);
const profileRawSchema = new schema.Entity('profiles', {}, {idAttribute: 'name'})
const profileSchema = new schema.Entity('profiles', {
    photos: [photoSchema]
}, {idAttribute: 'name'});
const normalizedProfiles = normalize(
    data.profiles,
    [profileRawSchema]
);

normalized.entities.profiles = normalizedProfiles.entities.profiles;
// here is what you want
const desiredResult = denormalize(normalizedProfiles.result, [profileSchema], normalized.entities);
```

[Docs for denormalize](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#denormalizeinput-schema-entities)